# Could not get unknown property 'com' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

Tags: reactjs, react-native

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-image-picker'.

> Could not get unknown property 'com' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.1",
```